# Laravel 5.4 Return as array not object

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

The following method is intended to return an array with another array, `'data'` and an Object (The result of some eloquent query).

It is however returning an array with two objects in it; $data is somehow being converted to an object with multiple child-objects, rather than being an array of objects. It should be noted that a `dd($data)` before the return statement reveals that it is indeed an array of objects. I think that somehow the Laravel middleware that handles response is returning this as an object instead...

Any idea how to work around this?

```
public function getTestData($id) {
    $participants = Participant::where('test_id', $id)->with('testRecords')->get();
    $finalRecordValue = TestRecord::where('test_id', $id)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();

    $data = [];

    foreach ($participants as $participant) {
        foreach ($participant->testRecords as $testRecord) { 
            if (!array_key_exists((int)$testRecord->capture_timestamp, $data)) {
                $data[$testRecord->capture_timestamp] = (object)[
                    'category' => $testRecord->capture_timestamp,
                    'value' . "_" . $participant->id => $testRecord->score
                ];
            } else {
                $data[$testRecord->capture_timestamp]->{"value" . "_" . $participant->id} = $testRecord->score;
            }
        }
    }

    return [$data, Auth::user()->tests()->findOrFail($id)];
}
```

Comment: **converted to an object with multiple child-objects**, its a bit vague, could you attach the `dd` result and expected result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this before excuting return sentence or in it:

```
array_values($data);
```